# JQUERY .css() with :hover pseudo-class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

The following code doesn't apply to the CSS classes with `:hover`, but does with everything else. Anyway to make it work with CSS classes that have `:hover`, or any pseudo-classes for the matter?

```
$('.nav-sidebar, .nav-sidebar:hover').css("border-color", "blue");
```

Comment: I do not understand this question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing this?

```
$('.nav-sidebar > .active, .nav>li').hover(function(){
   $(this).css("border-color", "blue");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Not sure why I didn't think of that. :D

Answer (score 0):

you can not use `:hover` selector in jquery like we do in css pseudo-classes selector.

In Jquery you can bind hover event using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Try this:

```
$('.nav-sidebar').css("border-color", "blue");
$('.nav-sidebar').hover(function(){
   $(this).css("border-color", "blue");
});
```